# How to import large mysql dumps into hadoop?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I need to import wikipedia dumps(mysql tables, unpacked files take about 50gb) into Hadoop(hbase). Now first I load dump into mysql and then transfer data from mysql to hadoop. But loading data into mysql takes huge amount of time - about 4-7 days. Is it possible to load mysql dump directly to hadoop(by means of some dump file parser or something similar)?

Comment: Why are you moving data into mysql ? Are you using it for further processing? If not then there is a way to put data directly into hadoop. Will add an answer based on what you reply

Comment: Maybe you can make use of https://sqoop.apache.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember - MySQL Dumps are almost entirely is set of insert statements. You can parse them in your mapper and process as is... If you have only few tables hard code parsing in java should be trivial.

Comment: Yes, it works. It takes only 1 hour to convert 760 million records dump to csv format. After that import to hadoop or mongo is trivial.

Comment: Hudvin , would you be able to share your script to parse .sql dump ?

Answer (score 1):

use [sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org) . A tool that import mysql data into HDFS with map reduce jobs.

It is handy.

Comment: As I know it requires data to be already in mysql(accessible via jdbc)

Comment: Sqoop can import from CSVs and Avro format files - see http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_file_formats

Comment: OP specifically talking about .sql dump files. can squoop handle this ?